# .Net Core Background Service on Kubernetes

Tags: azure, kubernetes, .net-core, azure-aks, background-service

I have a .Net Core Background Service that I hosted on Azure Kubernetes Service. Background Service needs connectivity to some remote Kafka Cluster to read messages as shown in the below image.

What are the possible options here to establish the traffic between services running inside Kubernetes and Confluent Kafka Cluster?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

kafka on aks

> What are the possible options here to establish the traffic between services running inside Kubernetes and Confluent Kafka Cluster?

Unfortunately, there’s no direct way of connecting your application running on AKS to Kafka broker,
But There are 3 ways to connect your Kafka resource to Azure AKS.

1. Is to run your Kafka in Azure HDInsight, which is an Azure service to run your Hadoop clusters.
   [image]
   You can deploy your .net background service application on your AKS and use it to connect to your Kafka with [kafka-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/kafka-node) package. This Deployment is similar to running your Kafka on HDInsight cluster. In this deployment > you deploy your Azure HDInsight cluster running kafka in one V-net and your AKS in another V-net and initiate the connection between the two v-net’s with **v-net peering** for the traffic to flow between kafka on Azure HDInsight and Azure AKS.
   [image]
   Image reference is from this MS document - [Use Azure Kubernetes Service with Kafka on HDInsight | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/kafka/apache-kafka-azure-container-services)
   If you have your own application that is receiving the topics from kafka you can create a docker image of your application and push it to Azure container registry on HDInsight not running on Azure,
   Example -
   a) You can create a docker image of the application that receives your kafka topics.

- `docker build -t kafka-aks-test`
  b) Log in to Azure container registry and tag your log in server with kakfa-aks-test.
- `docker tag kafka-aks-test <acrLoginServer>/kafka-aks-test:v1`
  c) Push the Image to registry.
  -`docker push <acrLoginServer>/kafka-aks-test:v1`
  d) Edit the kubernetes manifest file and replace microsoft with the log in server of ACR. then apply kubectl create.
  -`kubectl create -f kafka-aks-test.yaml`
  e) Get the IP Address of the kafka app running on AKS
  -`kubectl get service kafka-aks-test --watch`

2. Is to use strimzi operator
   You can deploy your kafka brokers with zookeeper pods running on Azure Kubernetes, with TLS client authentication for the brokers and mutual tls for producer/consumer clients authentication.
   a) Deploy an Azure Kubernetes Service on Azure Portal and create a kubernetes namespace :-

- kubectl create namespace tls-kafka
  [image]
  b) Install a strimzi operator :-
  -curl -L https://github.com/strimzi/strimzi-kafka-operator/releases/download/0.15.0/strimzi-cluster-operator-0.15.0.yaml \
  | sed ‘s/namespace: .*/namespace: tls-kafka/’ \
  | kubectl apply -f - -n tls-kafka
  [image]

c) In the above YAML file, Assign required role for `ServiceAccount`, `Roles`, `RoleBindings`, `ClusterRoles` & `ClusterRoleBindings which is necessary for RBAC enabled clusters for operator to function. alss, Create a custom resource to deploy our kafka in AKS by adding the below code :-

```
apiVersion: kafka.strimzi.io/v1beta1

 

kind: Kafka

 

metadata:

 

name: my-tls-cluster

 

spec:

 

kafka:

 

version: 2.2.1

 

replicas: 3

 

listeners:

 

tls:

 

authentication:

 

type: tls

 

config:

 

log.message.format.version: "2.2"

 

ssl.client.auth: "required"

 

tlsSidecar:

 

resources:

 

requests:

 

cpu: 200m

 

memory: 64Mi

 

limits:

 

cpu: 500m

 

memory: 128Mi

 

storage:

 

type: jbod

 

volumes:

 

- id: 0

 

class: managed-premium

 

type: persistent-claim

 

size: 64Gi

 

deleteClaim: false

 

zookeeper:

 

replicas: 3

 

storage:

 

type: persistent-claim

 

class: managed-premium

 

size: 32Gi

 

deleteClaim: false

 

tlsSidecar:

 

resources:

 

requests:

 

cpu: 200m

 

memory: 64Mi

 

limits:

 

cpu: 500m

 

memory: 128Mi

 

entityOperator:

 

topicOperator: {}

 

userOperator: {}
```

[image]
TLS is enabled on the kafka custom resource
d) Now, Perform kubectl apply

- kubectl apply -f tls-kafka.yaml -n tls-kafka
  Strimzi cluster will deploy the zookeeper and kafka brokers in your AKS.

3. Is to use third party tool like below :-
   https://portworx.com/blog/run-ha-kafka-azure-kubernetes-service/
   Deploy kubernetes cluster on azure and also portworx service to connnect to kafka on AKS.

Note- By default you can run any application on azure Kubernetes like you do in your native Kubernetes cluster, but Azure will only manage the AKS cluster for you, the application configuration on the cluster needs to be done by you!

References :-

1. [Use Azure Kubernetes Service with Kafka on HDInsight | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/kafka/apache-kafka-azure-container-services)
2. [Running Kafka on Azure Kubernetes Service | by Agraj Mangal | The Startup | Medium](https://medium.com/swlh/running-kafka-on-azure-kubernetes-service-d8d6882ade8)
3. [How to Run HA Kafka on Azure Kubernetes Service | Portworx](https://portworx.com/blog/run-ha-kafka-azure-kubernetes-service/)